# Zoom image on changing src in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

I am using [elevatezoom](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom) zoom jquery plugin to zoom image.But it is not working with AJAX.
I have a  tag and I am changing it's src attribute with jquery.So for the first time it works but when I changed image with jquery and then check zoom it takes the previous one.

This is my html code.

```
<img class="zoom_modal_img" id="quick_view_pimg" src="" data-zoom-image=""/>
```

and jquery code on click of some buttons I change src and data-zoom-image

```
function quick_view_fun(product_id,product_slug,img_src,img_src_large,name,price,size,color,material,product_qty){
    $('#quick_view_pimg').attr('src',img_src);
            $('#quick_view_pimg').attr('alt',name);
            $('#quick_view_pimg').attr('data-zoom-image',img_src_large);
            $("#quick_view_pimg").elevateZoom();
}
```

when I check in firebug both the variables changes src and data-zoom-image but it shows only first one zoomed image.

Please help me guys.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you have to reinitialize plugin once you changed src attribute

Comment: how to reinitialize it.As I am already calling it when I am changing src.

Comment: You should destroy it before but i don't know this plugin and apparently this plugin doesn't implement any destroy method.

Comment: is there any other plugin which can fulfill this task

Comment: I guess the problem is here in source code (init method): `self.imageSrc = self.$elem.data("zoom-image") ? self.$elem.data("zoom-image") : self.$elem.attr("src");` So try: `$("#quick_view_pimg").data("zoom-image",false).elevateZoom();` Should reinitialize image

Comment: @A.Wolff Awesome man how you all guys of stackoverflow find solutions of others plugin files.hats off to you. Butttt Sorry this changed but not the large image.I mean now it is showing on zomm that image on which I am zooming not the large image.

Comment: Not sure i understand your new issue, but could be a fix: `$("#quick_view_pimg").data("image",false).data("zoom-image",false).elevateZoom();` Or instead of just changing src attribute of image, you could just create a new one, it would be cleaner

Comment: cleaner solution would be: `function quick_view_fun(product_id,product_slug,img_src,img_src_large,name,price,size,color,material,product_qty){$("#quick_view_pimg").replaceWith($('<img>',{id:"quick_view_pimg",class:"zoom_modal_img",src:img_src,alt:name})).elevateZoom();}`

Comment: @A.Wolff this did not work but it worked with replacing img completely.Thanks for the help. Thankew